# How can I add an item to a Canvas after it has loaded?

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop

Items are shown on the canvas with help of a `DragEvent`.

The items get loaded by the `OnDrop` event. But I need to load some items without dragging them on the canvas. Is there an **Event Argument** like that is called automatically when the canvas loads??

```
protected override void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnDrop(e);
    DragObject dragObject = e.Data.GetData(typeof(DragObject)) as DragObject;
    if ( dragObject != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dragObject.Xaml) )
    {
        // elided
    }
}
```

I need to show item when the canvas loads without user doing the drag drop.

I also need to show the item automatically when the canvas loads.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: https://trycatchbug.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/wpf-how-to-add-elements-to-canvas/

Comment: how are your objects usually added? Are the stored in some ItemsControl via a binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a handler to the [`FrameworkElement.Loaded` Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<Canvas Loaded="YourEventHandler" ... />
```

...

```
public void YourEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas canvas = (Canvas)sender;
    // Add your item(s) here using canvas.Children.Add(someItem);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If that fixed your problem, please [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so that other users will know that this question has an answer.